# Macro to move cell and delete old row

Tags: excel, vba

I’m having a problem when I'm trying to create a macro, that loops through a column F. When it finds a value, when looping through the column it must move the cell one row up and delete the old row. But my macro is moving the number up, but it does not delete the old row.

I want the Macro to just move the cell one row up and delete the old row for every numerical value in column F. My Macro code is:

```
    Sub MoveDash()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim Cell As Range

    
    x = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For Each Cell In Range("F2:F" & x)
        If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
            Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Cell.Value
            Cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to be able to see the code you are using.... maybe edit your question and add it there?

Comment: because you're looping from the top and working your way down.  When deleting you need to loop from the bottom up OR build up a collection and delete them all in one go.

Comment: I have attachted the macro code now. @sous2817 do you have any idea how to do that for my code above? :)

Comment: Looping from the bottom up won't work here actually.

Comment: `Cell.ClearContents` only deletes the content of a cell, try `Cell.Delete Shift:=xlUp` Side note: I suspect the macro will not do what you expect if you do this. You`ll have to step through it to see exactly what happens and adjust acordingly

Comment: `delete the old row` Do you want to delete the row? or the cell in column F?

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I want it to delete the old row, where the value has been moved from

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Now it is just moving the cells 6 rows up and does not delete the old row

Answer (score 0):

The code copies numeric cell to up cell and delete the row.

Note: OP should double check the logic. If both F3 and F4 is numeric,

- the 1st round: F2 equals F3, delete row 3, row 4 shift up to row 3
- the 2nd round: check F3 again, F2 equals F3 (original F4) , delete row 3

The result (F2) of the 1st round is overwrote.

```vb
Sub MoveDash()
    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    x = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To x
        Set Cell = Cells(i, "F")
        If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
            Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Cell.Value
            Rows(i).Delete
            i = i - 1
            x = x - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding after 'Next Cell' and before 'End Sub':
Range("F2:F" & x).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: This doesn't compile ... `x` is a Long, not a Range

Comment: Oversight on my part. Changed Long x to Range("F2:F" & x).